# JQuery textarea value is empty

Tags: jquery

This type of question tends to immediately get a negative vote.  If you have the answer, please help!  Thanks.

I have a script that adds a textarea to the dom.  When I enter data and later try to retrieve it the value returns empty.

This successfully sets the value of the textarea:

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).val("ASDFASDF");
});
```

This successfully sets the css background property of the textarea:

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).css({"border":"2px solid red"});
});
```

But this does not return the value:

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I've tried .text(), .html(), .value - they all return nothing! It doesn't alert "undefined" or null but simply an empty value.

I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

**MORE INFO**

HTML is:

```
<textarea id="Bio" rows="4"></textarea>
```

JQuery Library:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Function is triggered by a button after the dom is loaded.

A simplified version of the code is here:
http://social-gamer.com/textarea.html

Comment: What do you get back in your alert?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck See this line: `It doesn't alert "undefined" or null but simply an empty value.`

Comment: Your code works fine here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/H6PCS/

Comment: My bad. I missed that. Any console errors?

Comment: I don't have a console errors.  I wonder if it's due to me adding this textarea to the dom?

Comment: That doesn't look like the HTML that reproduces the problem. It's only one textarea and your code is trying to deal with multiple textareas. You should work your code down to the simplest case that reproduces the problem

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help here. I posted an answer here in the end.  What a crazy issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, something else is the problem. You can [see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bjLJ/)

```
<textarea>Hello One</textarea>
<textarea>Hello One two</textarea>
<textarea>Hello One two three</textarea>

$("textarea").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

- What version of jQuery are you using?
- Is your code running before the DOM is loaded?
- What does your HTML look like? Are you assigning a value attribute to the textarea? That does not work, see http://jsfiddle.net/2bjLJ/1/

**Other Notes**

No need for `each` when you want to call a method on all the underlying objects.

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).val("ASDFASDF");
});

$("textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).css({"border":"2px solid red"});
});
```

It can just be

```
$("textarea").val("ASDFASDF");
$("textarea").css({"border":"2px solid red"});
```

However, when reading it, you do have to call each, otherwise you'll get the value from the first object in the jQuery collection

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bjLJ/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I know this is really basic and should work fine.  That's why it's blowing my mind here.  I'm using the JQuery at 

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

The code runs on click of a button.

I use .each because it'll need to run on multiple items.  My tests for css and setting val work which is frustrating.  There is no value="" attribute set.

Comment: @MadTurki No need for each, it will do exactly what your loop is doing when you are calling a setter method... Please post your HTML

Comment: @MadTurki, I went to your page, typed something in the textbox and the alert with its text did display

Comment: You're completely right...  So what did I cut out that made it work.  I'll keep looking!

Comment: Thank you for your help Juan.  Please see the answer I posted here... ugh!

Answer (score 3):

The problem ended up being a duplicate ID.  Normally I would check this first BUT I wasn't even accessing the element by its ID but simply by the input type "textarea".

So, even when targeting an element by class or simply by it's position in the DOM, if it has a duplicate ID it will fail.  I didn't really give this much thought earlier because I wasn't getting by ID!

Comment: And I was about to guess that because your HTML for the textarea did contain an ID. I'm guessing jQuery keeps a map of objects by ID?

Comment: I don't think you have the problem down yet, multiple elements with the same ID works fine (not that you should use it). http://jsfiddle.net/2bjLJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

how are you,

Listen, the TextArea is the only one of the inputs that don't get and set the value with val(), because when you put the value on textarea, you put inside of the tag.

There's an example

```
<textarea>Inside is the content so to 
get the content inside of tags you use HTML or TEXT</textarea>
```

So, when you try to get the data you must to do this:

```
$('textarea').text();
```

And for set the data of a textarea this:

```
$('textarea').text("HERE'S THE CONTENT.");
```

Here is a fiddle for you can see all i'm saying

http://jsfiddle.net/nfTVJ/

Good luck, and good bye